# 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop' warning not going away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, jsx

As far as I can tell I am passing in a unique key :/  I still can't seem to get rid of the warning telling me to add a unique key. I've tried by index, and by project.name but with no luck!

```
const Portfolio = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Portfolio',
      description:
        "The site you're on right now!  You can view the source code on github.",
      tech: ['React', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'Netlify'],
      live: 'https://arrantate.netlify.com/',
      code: 'https://github.com/arrantate/portfolio',
      img: portfolioIMG,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Weather App',
      description:
        'Gives you the current weather and some brief information about a city of your choice',
      tech: ['Python', 'Flask', 'API calls', 'Bootstrap', 'HTML'],
      live: null,
      code: 'https://github.com/arrantate/weather-app',
      img: weatherAppIMG,
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      {projects.map((project) => {
        return <Project key={project.id} project={project} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I simulated your issue https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-bush-f5rmw?file=/src/App.js 

No such error message. Can you provide more info?

Comment: Can you give us the warning you are getting? Maybe it's not coming from this place, since your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className='container'>
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  {
    projects.map((project, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={"_key"+index}>
          <Project project={project} />;
        </div>
      );
    })
  }
</div>
```